# Spreadsheet concatenate multiple cells based on match with dynamic column

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation

I'm trying to concatenate all the serial numbers that are part of a kit in a comma separated string in B:B on Sheet-2 based off of data from Sheet-1.

Is this even possible aside from a bunch of if statements inside a concatenate statement? I've been running my brain trying to figure out a way to do this via vlookup, index/match, might need a Google Sheets add-on as my searching in Excel showed a few VBA options that might work.

```
Get the column that has the kit selections, need to create the action off of this match.
=MATCH(TO_TEXT($A2),Sheet-1!$A$1:$G$1,0)
```

Sheet-1 has a list of serial numbers in A2:A, cells B1:G1 contain different kit numbers, in each cell B2:G100 if the kit contains the item it will have a '1' other wise the cell is empty.

```
S/N        Kit1        Kit2        ...        Kit7
GF367       1           1
BW274       1                                  1
...
BSP23                   1
```

Sheet-2 has a kit number in A2:A that correlates to one of the kits in Sheet-1!:B1:G1.

```
Kit#        S/N Comma String
Kit1        GF367,BW274
Kit2        GF367,BSP23
...
Kit7        BW274
```

Comment: re: *'Is this even possible...'* Yes it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in Sheet2!B2

```
=mid(arrayformula(concatenate(if(index(Sheet1!$B$2:$H$4,,match(A2,Sheet1!$B$1:$H$1,0))<>"",", "&Sheet1!$A$2:$A$4,""))),3,999)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that in the column A of Sheet2 is the transposed list of the first row header of the source data, try this in Sheet2!B2

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(substitute(trim(
 QUERY(IF(Sheet1!B2:E,Sheet1!A2:A,),"select *",ROWS(A:A)))," ",",")))
```

Explanation

IF is used to replace the 1's on the source cross tabbed data by the row labels, then this values are concatenated by using QUERY.

QUERY concatenates the rows values separating them by a space character. The above formula use this feature to concatenate the previous step resulting data values then TRIM is used to remove the extra spaces and SUBSTITUTE to replace the remaining spaces by a comma.